# What's the most elegant way to say "surmountable objection"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, idioms

"Surmountable" sounds so much weirder there than "insurmountable"..

As in:

> Was that a rejection? At the time it seemed like maybe he just had a few surmountable objections...

Comment: Nothing wrong with "surmountable".

Comment: But isn't there something more ELEGANT?

Comment: Elegance is in some degree subjective. Maybe if you edited your question to include the complete sentence, I might get a better idea of why you think "surmountable" is inelegant.

Comment: added some context cluezzzz

Comment: If you mean to say that the speaker wasn't expecting rejection, consider saying that the other person's objections had been "minor". While not a synonym for "surmountable", I think it makes more sense in context.

Comment: Also, I'm not entirely sure, but I think your question is off topic (writing advice).

Comment: No, it's "word-choice"? Is "word-choice" help writing advice?

Comment: I'd agree that there is no syntactical or semantic error in the OP, but that there is an almost comic effect because the word is so unusual in the attributive position. For style, if I didn't want the incongruous sound, I'd put 'surmountable' in brackets, or choose a suitable pre-modifier ('readily' or 'just about'), or reposition (it seemed like maybe he just had a few objections - all of which were surmountable -...).

Comment: I would have rephrased it as *At the time it seemed like maybe he  had a few objections, but nothing insurmountable.*

Comment: @Horace Loeb: Okay, then, maybe not.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly  *[superficial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superficial#Adjective)* (“Shallow, lacking substance”) would work well to modify *objections* in that context.  Depending on the larger context and the desired slant, some of the following terms might also work:
• *[minor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minor#Adjective)*, “Of little significance or importance”
• *[insignificant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insignificant#Adjective)*, “Not significant; not important, consequential, or having a noticeable effect”
• *[trivial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trivial#Adjective)*, “Of little significance or value”
• *[insubstantial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insubstantial#Adjective)*, “Lacking substance; not real or strong”
• *[nominal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nominal#Adjective)*, in its sense “Insignificantly small; trifling”
• *[secondary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secondary#Adjective)*, “Of less than primary importance”
• *[pro forma](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro_forma#Adjective)*, “For the sake of form only”
• *[perfunctory](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perfunctory#Adjective)*, “Done merely to discharge a duty; performed mechanically and as a thing of rote; done in a careless and superficial manner; characterized by indifference; as, perfunctory admonitions...”

For replacing both words (*objections* and its adjective) consider nouns
• *[cavil](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cavil#Noun)*, “A petty or trivial objection or criticism”
• *[nit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nit#Noun)*, a trivial detail (as in *[nitpicking](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nitpicking#Noun)*, “A process of finding or pointing out tiny details or errors, particularly if the pointed-out details seem insignificant or irrelevant to all but the finder”)
• *[minutia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minutia#Noun)*, “A minor detail, often of negligible importance”

Comment: +1 I too was thinking about:  *At the time it seemed like maybe he just had a few **nits** but no **showstoppers***...

Comment: If you told me he had nits, I'd spray him with insecticide.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the obstacles were of little consequence, jwpat7's suggestions offer many choices.

If you are looking for more "elegant" perhaps *[conquerable](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/conquerable)*.

Or perhaps an analogy

> What seemed like molehills have reared up into mountians.